Crop out area in Folium
I'm trying to crop a Folium map to a specific area but I can't get it to work. I made a rectangle on the map, and I want to save a png with just that area.
xlim = (df['longitude'].min(), df['longitude'].max())
ylim = (df['latitude'].min(), df['latitude'].max())
min_lon, max_lon = xlim
min_lat, max_lat = ylim
map = folium.Map(min_lat=min_lat, max_lat=max_lat, min_lon=min_lon, max_lon=max_lon,
                     zoom_control = False, control_scale=False, max_bounds=True)

folium.Rectangle(bounds=[[min_lat, min_lon], [max_lat, max_lon]], color='red', fill=False).add_to(map)
map.fit_bounds([[min_lat, min_lon], [max_lat, max_lon]])
map.save(...)

How can I save just the Rectangle object, cutting out everything arround it?
I tried using cv2 to use computer vision to find the red rectangle and crop it out, but it did not work for all maps since there are other red elements.

With a mix of selenium and PIL you should be able to open the resulting html map, take a screenshot and crop it the way you want. But it is not a simple task. I remember having a hard time over browser drivers...
